# Organizing controllers and modules in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking at the [*AngularJS's docs*](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04#controller) - I see the  regular ( as I know) pattern for declaring a controller : *(which supports minification)*

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
    phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
       function ($scope, $http) {
       ...
       }]);
```

**But** [*later on - they changed it to*](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#the-app-module) :

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Where **app.js** :

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);
```

And **controllers.js** :

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
   ...
  }]);
```

**Questions**

1) What's wrong with modularity in the first piece of code ? I dont see the problem. I have an App ,I attach controllers to it and that's it. what benefit do I gain from the second code ? *real-life scenario* will be much appreciated.

2) In the second code  - how come `app.js` is dealing with `phonecatControllers` where `phonecatControllers` is not on the page. ( it's js is loaded afterwards).

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with either example. But in either case, I don't see why you would want to have a global variable to keep track of the app (or controller in the second example). The second example allows you to organize controllers into its own module, services into its own, and so on, and then inject them into your main module. It makes your controllers and services and whatever more portable I guess.

Comment: As for a real-life scenario, I like to put **each** controller's code into separate files (and bundle/minify them later). I don't want a global variable (or variables) floating around just to declare components. So I declare component groups - `angular.module("testApp.controllers", []);`, declare the main module - `angular.module("testApp", ["testApp.controllers"]);`, and then add components to each group - `angular.module("testApp.controllers").controller("TestCtrl", function () {});` (each has its own file). I'm sure there's more detailed reasons, but I do it for organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece of code is better in my opinion and in fact, Angular is suggesting to go that way anyway:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

This approach is great at modularizing your code.  My apps are typically setup as:

```
modules
   |--home
      home-controller.js
      home.js
      home-service.js
      home.html
   |--user
      user-controller.js
      user.js
      user-service.js
      user.html
```

So that all code that belongs to a certain module is in its own file and is contained in a directory.  It's so much easier to keep things organized this way.

Here is what a typical module file (i.e. home.js above) would look like (example uses require.js):

```
define(function(require) {

    var angular = require("angular");
    var homeController = require("modules/home/home-controller");
    var homeService = require("modules/home/home-service");

    var homeModule = angular.module("Home", []);
    homeModule.controller("HomeCtrl", homeController);
    homeModule.service("HomeService", homeService);

    return homeModule;
});
```

The benefits of this approach are as I see them:

1. Keeps code cleanly organize into directories so that if I'm working on the home feature, I don't need to bounce all over the app looking for my files.
2. Keeps code contained in their own files, so I don't have a mammoth 'controllers' file with all controller code
3. Allows me to bundle up modules easily by simply minifying/packaging a directory.  I can then reuse these modules in other apps/systems that need them.
4. At unit test time, I can simply load one of these modules and I am effectively isolating my tests to just that module.  With the other approach, if I loaded the 'controllers' module, I am loading ALL controller code for my test, which is a waste.  Doing it the above way not only achieves great code isolation, but also speeds up my tests since I'm only loading exactly what I need to run my test.

To answer your second question, `app.js` is the main module of the Angular application.  In Angular, you add other modules as dependencies to your main app, so in your example, `phoneCatControllers` module is being added as a dependency to the main app.  The actual `controllers.js` file was either loaded through a `<script>` tag or through some type of AMD/CommonJS loading.  Then once its loaded, you take the name of the module and add it as a dependency to your main app module.

In the second example, modules are grouped by type so all controllers are added to one module, all services added to another module.  This is bad for the reasons I mentioned above.  It causes features of your app to be strewn all over the place and hard to find.  And it also requires you to load ALL controllers when you just want to test one of them.

With the first example (and Google/Angular's current style recommendations), you group by feature instead of grouping by file type i.e. a user directory or a home directory instead of a controllers directory or a services directory.

The reason that phoneCatControllers is able to be referenced as a module dependency is due to the way that Angular bootstraps the application.  The ng-app directive is evaluated during onDOMContentLoaded, so once all scripts have been loaded.  There are ways to manually bootstrap the application if you are using things like RequireJS but in your example, all scripts are loaded, then Angular bootstraps the application.

More information here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: in your code , what where/how homeModule looks like ?

Comment: My mistake. I left out one line where I create the module. Edited my answer from my phone so excuse lack of formatting. Will fix it in a bit

Comment: Can you please have a look at my second question ?

Comment: Edited my answer by adding three paragraphs at the end.

Comment: Added an additional paragraph at the end with some documentation that probably explains it much better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing in tutorials. First they work with a small example, where there is one module, and there is one controller. The relationship between the two is one to one. However, I think angular documentation would like to prepare you to embrace modularity.

Maybe it is hard to see in this example because there isn't much going on, but when you add factories and services and multiple controllers, in order to maintain clarity and reduce clutter, it is advisable to separate your code.

Comment: This is not an answer IMO. first sample is also modular in its own way