# Advantage defining a Angular Module / Service under a different name then the main application

Tags: angularjs

Where is the advantage in defining an angular module as such:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['appServices']);
var appServices = angular.module('appServices', []);

appServices.factory('someService', function ($http) {
    return { member:true }
});
```

... as opposed to:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('someService', function ($http) {
    return { member:true }
});
```

I cannot see a direct advantage, given that my single page app is named 'app'. Keep in mind I am new to Angular.

Comment: code portability is main advantage now, when lazy loading of modules is available that will be another advantage

Comment: what @charlietfl stated plus if you have different modules than any module that has any special dependencies can inject only into that module instead of the main app. this makes testing easier to maintain

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but this might help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982809/organizing-controllers-and-modules-in-angularjs/25982977#25982977

Comment: Follow-up question: Let's say, If I put the `appServices` in a different file, I will have to specifically load this file into my html (let's say index.html), correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage dependencies in modules. You code will be better organized and everyone can tell you what modules depend on other modules.

Thanks